# The server is stopped

Tags: visual-studio, appium, appium-android

I downloaded the latest version of Appium from the [GitHub](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.3.2). I have installed it on two Windows PCs,

- On first one it works fine.
- But on the second one, just by clicking "Start server v1.7.2" a window appear showing "The server is stopped".

What is wrong with the configuration?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any logs or additional information? Hard to tell what's wrong just from that...

Comment: Where could i found log for this appium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for above error.
It was due to firewall modified by an antivirus, it disables all open ports on this PC.

There can be around three solutions:

1. Format the PC will help us to get open ports, but it is not a recommended solution.
2. Uninstalling Antivirus can open blocked ports, by recovering firewall to its original state.
3. If the 2nd solution does not help then Uninstalling Antivirus and create a new User Account on PC, helps me to run Server successfully.